# How to determine the upper and lower bounds for the function $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$?

Tags: calculus

If I plot the equation mentioned on the topic, for $x \in [-10, 10]$, I get the following graph:

[$\frac{1}{1+e^x}$ for $x \in [-10,10]$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4LmX.gif)

The plotted graph can also be seen here: [http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F(1%2Be%5E-x)+x%3D%5B-10,10%5D]

Looking at the plotted graph one can notice that when $x$ reaches $-5$ the function gets really close to $0$ and any number lower than that makes almost no difference. As $x$ reaches $5$, the function gets close to $1$ and any number larger than that makes almost no difference.
My question is: how to determine these boundary values of $-5$ and $5$?

Thanks!

Comment: Your link goes to the graph of $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$

Comment: I think you actually mean $\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$. Anyway, it depends on the scale. As it happens $e^{-5}$ is less than $0.01$, so $\frac{1}{1+e^{-5}}$ is not much less than $1$ (and it gets closer as you go further out), while $\frac{1}{1+e^5}$ is not even $0.01$ (and it gets closer to zero as you go further out).

Comment: Oops, I meant $\frac{1}{1+e^x}$. I agree that the scale would make a difference but it seems pretty clear that -5 and 5 are points where the changes is so small that these could probably be considered boundary points. I am using this curve as a spline interpolation to draw a color gradient, and knowing these values of 5,-5 allow me to specify the canvas coordinates. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

As $x \to \infty$, $e^x \to \infty$ so that $ 1 + e^x \to \infty$ and therefore $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+e^x} = 0$$ This is your lower bound since it occurs when the denominator is maximized.  Now try to follow the same reasoning for $x \to -\infty$ to achieve a similar bound.

In case you were actually asking about $\frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}}$, you can follow a similar procedure.  Take $x \to \infty$ and note that $e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x} \to 0$ so that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{1 + e^{-x}} = 1$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware of the limits to reach those conclusions. I think I could have expressed myself a little bit better on what I was trying to achieve. When I asked about the [-5,5] range of values is because I am using this curve as a spline interpolation to draw a color gradient, so the range [-infinity, infinity] does not work well for that. Looking at the plot it is clear that around 5 and -5 the function is starting to reach its bounds, so I wanted to figure out a way to find those values without having to plot the graph. Does that make more sense?

Comment: You could evaluate your function at 5 and -5, then see the difference between the asymptotes of 1 and 0 to find out how close the values are to the asymptotes(I'm not sure if this is what you are asking about).

Comment: This comment together with Ian's comment about the scale just made me realize how to determine the values. I just need to equal the equation to 0.01 and 0.99. Those are values that satisfy my requirement for the spline interpolation (since now I have something that goes from 1% to 99% which is pretty good for me).

Answer (score 1):

Your graph will never reach $0$ or $1$. (These are the [asymptotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote) of this graph.)

You can verify they are never reached by trying to solve the function equal to these two values:

**Equal to zero**

$$0=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

cross multiply

$$0=1$$

No solution

**Equal to one**

$$1=\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}$$

cross multiply

$$1+e^{-x}=1$$

$$e^{-x}=0$$

Again no solution.

Comment: Unfortunately just proving that the function never reaches $0$ or $1$ is not proof that they are asymptotes, it's just proof that the asympototes are somewhere between (or including) $0$ and $1.$ Your argument would need to be paired with the fact that the limit as $x$ approaches $\pm \infty$ is $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I wasn't trying to prove they were asymptotes (the OP didn't ask that). I was just stating that there is no boundary.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_1 , x_2 \in [-10,10] $ be arbitrary.

For $x_1<x_2$ ,

Observe that

$$e^{x_1}<e^{x_2}$$ since $e^x$ is a strictly increasing function.

$$1+e^{-x_1}>1+e^{-x_2}$$

$$1+e^{x_1}<1+e^{x_2}$$

$$\frac{1}{1+e^{x_1}}>\frac{1}{1+e^{x_2}}$$

Thus $$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$$ is a strictly decreasing function.

So for $x \in [-10,10]$ ,

$$f(x)_{min}=f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{10}} >0 $$ and

$$f(x)_{max}=f(x)=\frac{e^{10}}{1+e^{10}} <1$$

You can show that $f_{min}$ and $f_{max}$ are its supremum and  infimum  . Hence upper bound and lower bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most standard and general way tosolve this is to approach it like you would approach an "Absolute Min/Max" problem. That is, set the derivative equal to zero to find local/relative max/min, and evaluate the function at the endpoints of the interval ("evaluate" at $\pm \infty$ in this case)

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1}{1+e^x}$$

$$f(x) = (1+e^x)^{-1}$$

$$f'(x) = -e^x (1+e^x)^{-2}$$

$$f'(x) = - \dfrac {e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$$

$$0 = - \dfrac {e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}$$

A fraction is be equal to zero if and only if the numerator is zero. Since $e^x$ is never zero for any $x$, this has no solution. Therefore, there are no relative extrema.

Now just combine Yushwuth's limit argument with this answer, and show that for $1$ $x$, $f(x)$ is between $0$ and $1$ ($f(0) = \dfrac 12$ for example) and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so after reading Ian's and Yushwuth's answers and comments I realized that what I was trying to accomplish was simple. I apologize for not being 100% clear on what I was trying to achieve in my question, but I hope the comments made it clear.

I am trying to use this function as a spline interpolation to draw a color gradient. So the idea is that the function will give me values between 0% and 100%. Considering this, what needs to be done to figure out what are the values for $x$ that approach that, I just need to calculate the following two equations:

$\frac{1}{1+e^x} = 0.99$

$x \approx 4.59$

and

$\frac{1}{1+e^x} = 0.01$

$x \approx -4.59$

These will give me the values for $x$ that allow me the range 1% to 99%.

Thanks for all other replies!

Comment: If you want to go all the way from 0% to 100% there are other functions which could work for you such as: $$-\frac{x^3}{500}+\frac{3x}{20}+\frac{1}{2}$$ with $x\in[-5,5]$